# How to access object property of indeterminate depth

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object with data stored at multiple levels ( a JSON-decoded document ) like this:

```
$db = (object) array(
    'simple_property' => 'value',
    'complex_property' => (object) array(
        'key' => 'value',
        'nested' => (object) array(
            'key' => 'value'
        )
    )
);
```

I want to be able to access and update data at any depth via reference. Example:

`$db->{ $key } = $new_value`

If `$key` is equal to `'simple_property'`, that works. But if `$key` is equal to `'complex_property->nested->key'`, it doesn't. Is there a way to accomplish what I want to, or am I looking at it incorrectly?

Comment: Have you looked into recursive functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get it to work that way. You'll have to create a function (or class method) to do something like that. As an example:

```
function getRecursiveProperty($object, $path)
{

  $array = explode('->', $path);

  if (empty($array))
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  foreach ($array as $property)
  {

    if (!isset($object->$property))
    {
      return NULL;
    }

    if (!is_object($object->$property))
    {
      return $object->$property;
    }

    $object = $object->$property;

  }

  return $object->$property;

}

function setRecursiveProperty($object, $path, $value)
{

  foreach (explode('->', $path) as $property)
  {

    if (!isset($object->$property))
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

    if (!is_object($object->$property))
    {

      $object->$property = $value;

      return TRUE;

    }

    $object = $object->$property;

  }

  return FALSE;

}

$key = 'complex_property->nested->key';

echo getRecursiveProperty($db, $key); // value

setRecursiveProperty($db, $key, 'new_value');

echo getRecursiveProperty($db, $key); // new_value
```

Comment: Definitely set me in the right direction. I needed to support arrays as well, so here's the code that ended up working for me:

http://pastebin.com/jVpTybZg

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `$db = json_decode($json, true);` instead of `$db = json_decode($json);`?

In this way you return an associative array instead of an object and you will not have these problems anymore.

> **json_decode ( string $json , bool $assoc)**
>
> - **json**
>
>   The json string being decoded.
>
>   This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.
> - **assoc**
>
>   When **TRUE**, returned objects will be converted into
>     associative arrays.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php